# What is the right way to access parent object in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, constructor, pixi.js

I'm trying to acess GameManager instance.levels but always returns as undefined.
I could't use this.instance because it belongs to GM

```
class GameManager { 
    instance = { levels: { } }
    constructor(){ 

    }

    Level = class { /* extends ENGINE.Container, ENGINE IS NOT MINE */
        constructor(name) {
            // super(); /* EXTENDS ENGINE.CONTAINER */
            
            instance.levels[name] = this; /* new ENGINE.Container(); */
        }

        tick = function(){ /* will be overridden */}
    }
}

const game = new GameManager();
var loadScreen = new game.Level('ls');
loadScreen.tick = function(){
  
}
```

Comment: Why are you nesting classes like this?

Comment: @evolutionxbox does it really matter why?

Comment: What do you mean? shouldn't i use like that?

Comment: It might solve your issue. Why not pass the `game` instance into the constructor for `Level`? `loadScreen = new Level('ls', game)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While nesting classes itself is already a bit hacky, you can get even hackier and use an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to expose the `GameManager` as a scoped variable:

```js
class GameManager {
    instance = { levels: {} }
    constructor() {

    }

    Level = (instance => class {
        constructor(name) {
        }

        getGame = () => instance;
    })(this);
}

const game = new GameManager();
var loadScreen = new game.Level('ls');
console.log(loadScreen.getGame());
```

But again, might be better off not nesting the classes and instead using a factory method, e.g. `loadScreen = game.createLevel('ls')`. The factory method could then call the non-nested version like `new Level(game, 'ls')`.

Comment: mega-hacky ftw!